# kotlin test whith mockito: comparison Failure

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

I am trying to cover with test simple presenter, which looks like next:

```
class Presenter{
    fun getData(params:SomeParams) {
        usecase.execute(getObservable, params)
    }

    private fun getObservable() = object :DisposableObserver<SomeData>{
        override fun onComplete() {}
        override fun onNext(t:SomeData) {}
        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {}
    }
}
```

here is my simple test:

```
@Test
fun getContacts() {
    presenter.getData()

    var observer = Mockito.mock(DisposableObserver::class.java) as DisposableObserver<SomeData>
    verify(useCase).execute(observer, someParams)
}
```

and after last line i get next error:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
    useCase.execute(
    com.test.PresenterTest$getObservable$o$1@579d011c,
    kotlin.Unit
    );
    -> at com.test.execute(UseCaseObservable.kt:37)
    Actual invocation has different arguments:
    useCase.execute(
    com.test.Presenter$getObservableObserver$1@733c423e,
    kotlin.Unit
    );
    -> at com.test.Presenter.getObservable(Presenter.kt:43)
```

so what i am getting this error and how to avoid it and cover this method with test? thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this question (and in particular how to use Mockito's ArgumentCaptor class for such cases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47565887/how-to-capture-arguments-which-are-functions-using-argumentcaptor-mockito/47566488#47566488

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compare two different instances with eachother: one created by Mockito (`mock`), and one created by `Presenter` (`getObservable`). The two are not equal to eachother, so Mockito gives the comparison failure.

Instead, you can use `any`:

```
verify(useCase).execute(any(DisposableObserver::class.java), eq(someParams))
```